# Document.querySelector returns multiple branches

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape this [website](https://sheet2site-staging.herokuapp.com/api/v3/index.php?key=1F7gLiGZP_F4tZgQXgEhsHMqlgqdSds3vO0-4hoL6ROQ&g=1&e=1) and fetch the table and save it to an array

To try debugging my errors, I used the console tab in CTRL + SHIFT + I in chrome. There I used the console to type in my command.
The command was :

```
document.querySelectorAll("tr")
```

I know how to save the data to an array and it even works, but only up to the first 99 elements. This screenshot is what I get as the output when I run the command.[image]

In this, the output is split up into 3 parts. Each part covers 99 elements.

Is there a way I can get all of the data in one part?

My code:

```
const text = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`tr > td`), element => element.textContent));
console.log(text.length);
```

Output:

```
99
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data *does* all exist in one part, in the NodeList returned by `querySelectorAll` - what you're seeing is simply the JavaScript console trying to make manual navigation of the properties easier by splitting them up for display in the console. Try:

```
const trs = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
console.log(trs.length);
```

and you'll get all 202 or 203. You should be able to scrape all the data as needed, eg:

```
const arr = [...trs].map(tr => tr.children[0].textContent)
```

gives you `["SPAC Ticker", "SPAC Ticker", "AACQ"` etc, for as many elements as there are in the NodeList - just as an example.

Comment: Text.length returns 99. The website I use has a "load more" button. They only show 99 data entries per click. So, if I click the load more, then I get 99 more values.

Comment: Works just fine here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg9mX.png I didn't click anything. Your screenshot shows a length above 200 as well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/noRXA.png see `length: 203` and `NodeList(203)`. Please double check, it should be working.

Comment: It works in the website, but in my actual code, it doesn't.

Comment: Pls help me fix this.

Comment: I installed Puppeteer, and it still looks to work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/46ho2.png

Comment: WHATTTTT??! HOW? Is that the same code as mine?

Comment: Nearly, I just changed the `tr > td` to just `tr` to show the number of rows. (`tr > td` gives the total number of TDs, which is a lot larger)

Comment: Sounds really strange, if you're really getting a different result. Perhaps the site displays different results depending on the fetching user's IP or something..? I tried connecting to it both from the US and from Canada and it gives the same result, a bit more than 200 rows

Comment: THANK U SO MUCH. It worked for me too. U have no idea how happy i am

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the entire code? The end got chopped off a bit. I just want to compare it.

Comment: It's the same as yours, just with `tr` instead. `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr')`

Comment: Okay. Thank you.